# regex extracting specific elements in strings

Tags: python, regex

Im need to extract the BIN, Tracking and Book Identification numbers from the following string.

```
BIN: 1234\nTracking #: 56789\nBook Identification #: 121212
```

I've created a regex using Python which allows me to get BIN number using this.

```
^BIN:(.*)
```

This allows me to get the entire block after BIN, However, I can't work out how to just get value for BIN and the other items.

https://regex101.com/r/rK4gN4/1

Comment: You might want something like `^BIN:\s*(\d+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add more groups, like this:

`^BIN:.*?(\d+).*?#:\s+(\d+).*?#:\s+(\d+)`.

I am using `#`s as the point where to start looking for Tracking and Book Identification details. Note that it is important to use lazy matching with `*?`.

Here is an [updated example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rK4gN4/2).

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [5-9]   `1234`
2.  [22-27] `56789`
3.  [51-57] `121212`
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI3cQ1/3)**

Try this regex:

```
^BIN:\s?(\d+)\s?Tracking #:\s?(\d+)\s?Book Identification #:\s(\d+)
```